# Problema con binarios al instalar snappy pdf en sevidor compartido

Tags: laravel, pdf, dompdf

tengo instalado los binarios de snappy PDF en windows en programa files funciona bien en mi servidor local, pero subi mi proyecto a 000webhost y no funciona sin los binarios, entiendo que los binarios deben correr en el sistema operativo del servidor, en este caso creo que no tengo acceso, que solucion puedo aplicar para solucionar este problema, ya intente colocando los binarios en la carpeta vendor y subirlo al servidor compartido y no funciona, aunque en el servidor local funciona correctamente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esto pasa cuando lo uso en el servidor compartido 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Yo te recomendaría lo siguiente.
Las rutas en tu archivo config/snappy tratalos desde el .env del proyecto asi.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora desde tu archivo .env vas a señalar las ruta asi
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y al final debes retirarle el .exe

Porque todo esto ? en windows se hace de esta forma, porque se compila por medio de unos ejecutables (.exe), mientras en linux se compila con los archivos binarios guardados en la carpeta vendor que como puedes ver en mis rutas, no tienen extensión.

Porque desde el .env, para esto es este archivo, para configurar variables cambiantes de acuerdo al servidor donde corren, en windows las url se separan con \  mientras en linux con / , por esto es mejor este tipo de rutas, hacerlo desde el .env.

Espero que esto te pueda ayudar, saludos.

Comment: Bien amigo. Pero estaría apuntando a binarios que no tengo instalados no se que sistema operativo usa el servidor de 000webhost   y tampoco tengo acceso al sistema operativo

Comment: Vale, realmente no hay que instalarlos, se descargan y se deben anexar en la carpeta bin, como lo indica mi ruta despues de vendor, es lo unico que debes hacer, mientras la url de tu proyecto apunte bien a estos archivs, ha de funcionar, a nivel de codigo puedes utilizar base path como lo tienes, pero el resto de la ruta, ojala fuese desde el .env